# Matrix norm and perturbation problem on finite dimensional $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ equipped with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ given by $$\|x\|^2=x^tXx$$ where $X$ is a matrix and $x\in V$ is in matrix form. Further let us assume that vectors evolve in time $t$ according to the equation $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=Ux$$
a) Find general sufficient conditions on $X$ to ensure that $\|\cdot \|$ is a norm.

b) Consider small perturbations $\delta y$ from a particular initial condition $y(0)$. How would one calculate the $\delta y(0)$ which evloves into the largest small perturbation $\delta y(t)$ after a small time interval $t$? Largest here is taken to mean with respect to the norm. Further how would one calculate the growth in the size of the perturbation? Hint: Assume that a linearization of the PDE above is appropriate

First of all, what is that partial derivative mean? $x$ is now a vector valued function with time variable $t$? Then how would you proceed? I m bit confused. Help is appreciated

Comment: a) $X$ must be positive-definite

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For (a), think about the axioms of an inner-product and why the standard identity matrix $X = I$ satisfies this for the "standard" norm on an $n$ dimensional space. Also note that if $X$ is positive definite symmetric, then Cholesky decomposition for example gives you that $X = L^TL$ for some real-valued square matrix $L$.

For your last set of questions, the vector equation $x' = Ux$ gives the partial derivatives for entries in $x$ (although in terms of functions of $x$, rather than functions of $t$). Each entry in $x'$ and corresponding entry in the vector $Ux$ gives the derivative equation for one coordinate in $x$. And yes, you are right, the differential equation says that $x$ is a vector-valued function parametrized by one parameter, $t$.